# I want to do scraping with Selenium in python

Tags: python, windows, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I have CHROME - version 116.0.5845.97 (official version) (64 bits). The ChromeDriver version I installed in the same folder is 116.0.5845.96. I couldn't find the exact same version.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))#, options=options
 
except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", str(e))
```

When I run the code in Python, I get a message:

> Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the versions, if both of them is updated, then it's fine, here's the way that i initialize `driver`:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Specify the path to the Chrome driver executable(you need to download and put it somewhere)
chrome_driver_path = "C:\\Users\\akram\\Desktop\\Work\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe"
# Initialize the Chrome WebDriver
service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service(chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
url = "URL_TO_SCRAP"
driver.get(url)
```

Install webdriver, if it's not with: `pip install selenium`.